# Save video played time to db

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

I need to display a video in HTML page and save every 10 seconds to a db the current video percentage already played. 
I want that the page (client side ) send a hidden form that contain the percentage to the server that must write it to db.
If post to same page the video restart so I want send the form to blank frame.
While the video is running the percentage is not write to db. The db is write only when i push "ExitFromVideo" submit button but percentage is always 0
what am I doing wrong?

In order to do this I put this code in php page:

```
...
<center>
      <video id="video" width="320" height="240" preload="auto" controls autoplay>
       <source src="video/video_0_0_0.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <p><input style="text-align:center;" type="submit" class="button-three" name="ExitFromVideo" value="Exit From Video"/>

      <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
      <form id="form1" method="get" action="about:blank" target="votar">
        <input id="str_s2" name="percentage" type="hidden">
      </form>
    </center>
    ...

    <script>
    // Update the count down every x second
    (function () { function checkTime(i) {  return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i; }
        function startTime() {
            //document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            t = setTimeout(function () { startTime() }, 5000);
            myFunction();
            document.forms["form1"].submit();
        }
        startTime();
    })();

    function myFunction()
    {
      var x = document.getElementById("video");
      var z = "";
      if(x != null ) {z = parseInt( x.length(0) / 100 * x.played.end(0), 10); }
      else {z="null";}
      document.getElementById("str_s2").value = z;
      //From here the client must (by post) ask to server to save percentage already seen
    }
    </script>
```

in included php page that catch the post message:

```
if(isset($_POST['percentage']))
{
  $Percentage = intval($_POST['percentage']); 

  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
  $videotoplay = $_SESSION['videotoplay'];
  $ArgumentSelected = $_SESSION['ArgumentSelected'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM secure_login.UserDataVideo WHERE UserId = $userid AND Video = $videotoplay AND Argument = $ArgumentSelected AND Profile = 0 limit 1";
  $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1)
  {
   $query = "UPDATE secure_login.UserDataVideo SET Percentage = $Percentage  ModifiedTs = NOW()
   WHERE UserId = $userid AND Video = $Video AND Argument = $ArgumentSelected AND Profile = 0 LIMIT 1";
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  }
  else
  {
    $query = "INSERT INTO secure_login.UserDataVideo(UserId, Video, Argument, Profile, Percentage, CreationsTs, ModifiedTs)
    VALUES ($userid, $videotoplay, $ArgumentSelected, '0', $Percentage, now(), now() )";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could simply post the value using Ajax every 10 sec instead of posting a full form into a new window.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank You but simply not for me :), can You explain with an little example or link?

Comment: @Dharman Thank You, I didn't know there was a security problem, I will use prepared statements.

Comment: When the video starts, start a timer `setInterval()` for every 10 sec. In the timer callback, check the position of the video and do an ajax request to your back end with the data you need (like the percentage, what video it is etc.) If you want to learn more about ajax, you can google it. There are _many_ tutorials out there.

Comment: It's not just a security problem. Your SQL has a mistake in it. It won't accept anything other than an integer. If you want to pass values to SQL you must bind them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use this code and it work properly.

```
<script>
// Update the count down every 1 second only in video view
var x = setInterval(function()
{
  var timerss = document.getElementById("timerx");
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  if(video != null)
  {
    timerss.textContent = Math.round(video.currentTime / video.duration * 100) + "%";
    var Percentage = Math.round(video.currentTime / video.duration * 100);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'server.php', true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200)
        {
            // Request finished. Do processing here.
            //alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send("writepercentage=" + Percentage +"&currenttime=" + video.currentTime);
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

php server page:

```
if(isset($_POST['writepercentage']) && isset($_POST['currenttime']))
{
 $Percentage = $_SESSION['percentage'] = intval($_POST['writepercentage']);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM UserDataVideo WHERE UserId = {$_SESSION['userid']} AND Video = {$_SESSION['quiztoshow']} AND Argument = {$_SESSION['ArgumentSelected']} AND Profile = {$_SESSION['profile']} limit 1";
 $results = mysqli_query($dbuserdata, $query);
 $currenttime = intval($_POST['currenttime']);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($results) != false)
 {
  $query = "UPDATE UserDataVideo SET Percentage = $Percentage, LastSecondPlayed = $currenttime, ModifiedTs = now()
  WHERE UserId = {$_SESSION['userid']} AND Video = {$_SESSION['quiztoshow']} AND Argument = {$_SESSION['ArgumentSelected']} AND Profile = {$_SESSION['profile']} limit 1";
  $results = mysqli_query($dbuserdata, $query);
 }
 else
 {
  $query = "INSERT INTO UserDataVideo(UserId, Video, Argument, Profile, Percentage, LastSecondPlayed, CreationsTs, ModifiedTs)
  VALUES ({$_SESSION['userid']}, {$_SESSION['quiztoshow']}, {$_SESSION['ArgumentSelected']}, {$_SESSION['profile']}, $Percentage, $currenttime, now(), now() )";
  mysqli_query($dbuserdata, $query);
 }
}
```